# Webservice with .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, timeout

I have an application that when run as a windows application takes around 4 secs to compute, but when run as a webservice, it takes a long time to compute (until a timeout).

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?
I am assuming that since the code is exactly the same, there are no problems such as infinite loops ..... it seems that it just takes longer.

Do you have an idea what might the problem be?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

use profiler like dotTrace. it will show you all reasons of working slow